What should be the comparison key when I have a coordinate pair binary tree
I want to create a binary tree out of 2d points. What should be the key to be compared for the binary tree?

don't use tags merely to attract users. When I get attracted to a question by a tag just to find that nothing in the question needs the tag my first reflex is to downvote. And the second to edit ;)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Oh sorry. Thanks for the information.

coordinates maybe?

When you have two dimensions, you would not use a plain binary tree, but a k-d tree, with k=2, or a quadtree
